# Regex for non negative and non zero for the format ###.##

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a requirement to validate some inputs which should be in format ###.##

Invalid inputs are:

```
-11.10          ==> no negative
000.00 or 0     ==> 0 not allowed should be positive
```

Valid inputs are:

```
1
11
111
1.1
11.11
111.11
```

I have tried with the following regex [^([^-]\d{0,2}(.\d{1,2})?)$](https://regex101.com/r/rP8yO1/1) which fulfills my requirements except it's accepting 0 which I don't want. How I can modify my regex so only 0's do not get matched?

Thanks For Help

Comment: `If (thatString > 0 && thatString is in format /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/) { CORRECT VALUE. }`

Comment: `if(x<=0) { ERROR! }`

Comment: Add `(?!0*\.?0+$)` after `^`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   yes you got it. Thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: ClasG posted a similar solution with reverse logic. You may use it.

Comment: Do you need to validate the `###.##` part, or is it certain to be the input's format?

Comment: can someone tell me why his regex accept: 111.11? I thought, his regex only match 0 or 2 digit before a `.`

Comment: @Ramadoka: The `[^-]` matches any symbol but a `-`, so it matches a digit. The expression can match `$11.11`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,3}(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

It should do it for you.

It starts with a positive look-ahead to make sure there's a digit other than `0` present.
Then it matches 1-3 digits, optionally followed by a `.` and 1-2 digits.

[Your regex101 updated](https://regex101.com/r/rP8yO1/3).

Answer (score 0):

`([0-9]){1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` is the expression you are searching for.

`([0-9]){1,3}` = any number sequence with a length from 1 up to 3

`(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` = "?" maybe there is a float tail

`(\.[0-9]{1,2})` = float tail must start with a dot and decimal numbers have to be up to 2

There is a way to except all zero sequences but it will waste your time for no reason, as you can simply check it with `if myNum > 0`.
It will work for negative values also, but this regex excludes them too.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$|^0\.[0-9]+$
```

This will work for you. It accepts all valid positive decimal numbers excluding 0.